# Track cookie JSESSIONID delete in client side

Tags: tomcat, cookies, session-cookies

I have a server which stores the client side cookie of session as JSESSIONID,but if user delete this in the client side from the cookie store, client sends a new sessionid, how can i identify this in server, if you tell by

`request.getSession(false);,` than how to differentiate between first request and this request?

Answer (score 1):

If the client carries JSESSIONID, but the method `request.getSession(false)` returns `NULL`, there is no way for us to differentiate whether the session has expired or whether the client modifies the JSESSIONID.

The first request typically does not carry JSESSIONID cookie. You can use this information to differentiate whether the client modify the JSESSIONID.

That said, typically, we let the web container to manage the session for us. So, we don't read/write JSESSIONID cookie. If you really need to work directly with JSESSIONID cookie, perhaps you can explain more the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am using the session to store some data, and i am using spring, but if the client is deleting the JSESSIONID, server is not able to pic the previous session so i am not getting my data, so if such tampering with the JSESSIONID happens,I want the system to logout or if someway i can hide the visiblity of the JSESSIONID.